# Error: setuid user id does not exist npm ERR! when npm install forever -g

Tags: node.js

os: debian 7

node.js is installed in the defalut folder .

> root@10-4-4-159:/usr/local# npm install forever -g
>
> npm ERR! Error: setuid user id does not exist
>
> npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/uid-number/uid-number.js:44:16
>
> npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:635:7)
>
> npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
>
> npm ERR!     at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
>
> npm ERR!     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)
>
> npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
>
> npm ERR!     http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! or email it to:
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
>
> npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "forever" "-g"
>
> npm ERR! cwd /usr/local
>
> npm ERR! node -v v0.10.21
>
> npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.11
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     /usr/local/npm-debug.log
>
> npm ERR! not ok code 0

Comment: Did you solve the problem ?

Answer (score 8):

**Work around for this issue:**

Open the file below in your editor:

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/uid-number/uid-number.js`

Goto [line 11](https://github.com/isaacs/uid-number/blob/master/uid-number.js#L11), then replace `uidSupport = process.getuid && process.setuid` with `uidSupport = false`

Comment: For NAS-boxes (e.g. entware-based QNAP NAS extensions), the path of the file to be fixed is `/opt/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/uid-number/uid-number.js`.

Comment: thanks for posting this, i'd give more upvotes if i could.

Answer (score 2):

For those who want just a quick shell oneliner to fix the issue.
**Linux**:
`sed -i'' -r 's/^( +, uidSupport = ).+$/\1false/' /path/to/uid-number.js`

**FreeBSD**:
`sed -i'' -e -E 's/^( +, uidSupport = ).+$/\1false/' /path/to/uid-number.js`

Answer (score 1):

**Root cause**: npm assumes `nobody` as user while calling [process.getuid](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_getuid), which fails if your system does not have an user called nobody.

**Solution**: create a new user called `nobody` and try again!

`sudo adduser --no-create-home --shell /dev/null --disabled-password --disabled-login --gecos '' nobody`