# sh: 1: node: Permission denied

Tags: node.js, npm

Tried to run this command on ubuntu 18.04

```
npm install -g pngquant-bin
```

but I got this error,

```
[..................] | fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule npm-conf@1.1.3 checking installable status
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/bin/pngquant -> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/lib/node_modules/pngquant-bin/cli.js

> pngquant-bin@5.0.0 postinstall /root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/lib/node_modules/pngquant-bin
> node lib/install.js

sh: 1: node: Permission denied
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! pngquant-bin@5.0.0 postinstall: `node lib/install.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pngquant-bin@5.0.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-08-12T18_08_02_197Z-debug.log
```

Do you do you know how to deal with this?
I tried every solution found in this [articles](https://github.com/imagemin/pngquant-bin/issues/78) yet not succeeded.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Got the same error `sh: 1: node: Permission denied`

So this worked for me

```
npm config set user 0
npm config set unsafe-perm true
```

Comment: This is the correct answer if you run NPM under root account. But please remember that it's unsafe (unless you know what're you doing).

Comment: Wow, I'm happy to find that this works, but also disappointed that the error message is so misleading. I ran into this using `nvm` on a Raspberry Pi 3 (raspbian image from April 2019) and fought it for over an hour. Where might one make a PR to print out a warning like *"Refusing to run with unsafe permissions (e.g. root user). See <URL> for more information."*?

Comment: If you know, could you expand on what is actually causing the permission problem?

Comment: This solution worked for me. I only had to use `npm config set user 0`. Now I understand why this is not safe but working after reading [this](https://timjrobinson.com/fixing-node-gyp-permission-denied-when-running-as-root/) document. Quote: "... as installing modules as root means they could do anything to your system."

Comment: It tells me: `user` is not a valid npm option

Comment: it says sh: 1: next: Permission denied

Answer (score 115):

These issues happen because of broken packages. Go to the main folder. If using Linux use command

```
sudo rm -rf node_modules
```

After that run this command if you are using yarn

```
yarn install
```

If you are using npm run this command

```
npm install
```

Comment: It's better to try this first. It worked for me.

Comment: This is the best option, try this before moving into unsafe territory.

Comment: We use a mix of `pnpm` and `npm` for different projects - run the wrong command on the wrong project and you end up here and removing `node_modules` is the fix

Answer (score 18):

Solved my problem `chmod -R a+x node_modules`

As far as my understanding goes the os is blocking your ability to execute commands described in `node_modules` so by my understanding what this command does is say everything in `node_modules` is okay to execute.

By the time I found the solution it was 4 AM, so I didn't really bother to figure out what I actually did. If someone knows what `-R a+x node_modules` does exactly feel free to drop it in the commands and I will make an edit.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 11):

In my case it was a silly typo, I was forgotten to add `node` into the front of the start command in `package.json`. So I've changed:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "app/server.js"
}
```

... to:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app/server.js"
}
```

Comment: I feel silly, I did the same thing. You prolly saved me from a wild goose chase

Answer (score 8):

in fact, `npm` can't use `root` account to install anything. if you use `root` account, `npm` will create a non-permission account to install. in this case, if the package need to execute `writeFile` or other operation which need permission, the error `node: Permission denied` will be raised.

so, you can choose optional arbitrary under:

- npm install xxx --unsafe-perm
- npm config set unsafe-perm true
- create high-permission account dedicate to execute `npm install`

Answer (score 5):

The `/root/.npm/...` log path in your original message shows you're already running as root, and (despite what others advise) I'd say this is most likely **causing** your problem.

My (limited) experience running Node as root is that most `npm install` runs get quite a long way, but then fail with some variation on the error you showed.  The only reliable solution I've found is to **not run Node or npm as root at all** on Ubuntu.  Just use a normal user account to download and unpack the Node installation.

At least one problem with running as root for me turned out to be because some dependency-of-a-dependency `npm install` script was calling `setuid` to switch to a less-privileged user.  For some reason, it chose UID 500—which doesn't exist on Ubuntu—and consequently lost all its privileges.  The 'Permission denied' errors were therefore *because* I was running as root; `setuid` doesn't work for a normal user.

I believe this is related to [Error: setuid user id does not exist npm ERR! when npm install forever -g](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19862974).

Answer (score 2):

I make the chown to project user owner (in USERID) dir and resolv the "permission denied" problem:

sudo chown -R USERID.USERID *

Answer (score 2):

Additionally (and this might be useful for `docker`) you can override this configuration setting globally via the environment variable `npm_config_user` -- for example:

```
ENV npm_config_user=root
```

Comment: This is probably a bad practice on a personal machine. That being said I use docker, WSL2, for dev environments and don't generate a user. this worked for my when trying to install story-book via `npx sb init`

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same error an nothing really helped. I found a [medium article explaining how to set up an angular build management](https://medium.com/geekculture/setup-gitlab-ci-pipeline-for-angular-9cce853ef281). For some reason adding

```
- npm link @angular/cli@13.2.5
```

to my build script made it. I basically added all of the recommendations above. So my build script now looks like this

```
- ...
- npm config set user 0
- npm config set unsafe-perm true
- npm i --force
- npm link @angular/cli@13.2.5
- ...
```

I hope it helps! I would be happy if someone could explain why it actually worked.

Answer (score 2):

I run `chmod -R 755 node_modules` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but maybe someone still need some help.

This errors often is displayed because you have defined in the package.json just the path. For example:

```json
{
  // more definitions
  "scripts": {
    // other scripts
    "getPax8Products": "<filepath>",
    // more scripts
  },
  // more definitions
}
```

In this case, you need to:

1. Add the following lines in the very beggining of the script

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';
```

2. Give the file execution permission

```sh
# in UNIX based
chmod +x <filepath>
```

You also can modify the package.json and add the node command. However, you need to be aware that NPM will run in the script's directory:

```json
{
  // more definitions
  "scripts": {
    // other scripts
    "getPax8Products": "node <filepath>",
    // more scripts
  },
  // more definitions
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Deploying with Docker:

- make sure **/node_modules** is deleted or added to dockerignorefile
- make sure **/dist** is deleted or added to dockerignorefile

the problem was solved for me by deleting both files
and build them in the container

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had not installed my dependencies. node_modules did not exist, but I had jest installed globally apparently. Running `npm ci` and then running `npm test` solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. `npm install lite-server --save-dev`
2. `packages.json`:

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "dev": "lite-server",
   },

   "devDependencies": {
   "lite-server": "^2.6.1"
   }
   ```
3. `npm run dev`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I stuck with same issue when tried to install packages into AWS Sagemaker instance

The issue coming because NPM by default install new global packages into ~/.npm-global
When you run npm install -g  by root, npm is try to install package into /root/.npm-global/..., and stuck with access denied.

Simply workaround to re-config global folder for npm.
(https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)

Here is example of install obj2gltf

```
mkdir /npm-global
npm config set prefix '/npm-global'
export PATH=/npm-global/bin:$PATH
npm install -g obj2gltf
```

Answer (score 0):

I had that error too and tried the above solutions without any change. My error was caused because I had Windows (11) with a WSL and NVM installed on both operating systems. I had to uninstall NVM on my Windows to resolve the conflicts.

I think if you develop in your WSL and have a resource installed on both operating systems, a dependency might point to the wrong operating system with the resource (in my case to the NVM on Windows). The WSL user didn't have sufficient permissions to perform any execution on the Windows machine, which lead to the error.

Answer (score -4):

I have the same issue. to fix it run:

chmod -R 777 YOUR_BASE_ANGULAR_DIR/

777 only in localhost

Comment: With 777 you are giving access and execution rights to the whole world. Very bad security issues might ensue. This is not recommended at all.

Comment: Do not use this answer, it is not safe to make files world readable/writable.

Answer (score -5):

you need root user permission, just add `sudo` keyword before the command and write your password

```
sudo npm install -g pngquant-bin
```

Comment: Never use root permission when installing npm packages

Answer (score -9):

Try to install node at project folder

```sh
npm install node
```