# Running npm run serve on an NTFS mounted filesystem

Tags: linux, vue.js, npm, permissions, fstab

I am attempting to create a Vue application on an NTFS-formatted drive that I have mounted on my Ubuntu operating system. However, running the command `vue serve` produces the following error:

```
Running npm run serve

> vue-start-spa@0.1.0 serve
> vue-cli-service serve

sh: 1: vue-cli-service: Permission denied
/home/chumbers/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/execa/index.js:174
        err = new Error(`Command failed: ${joinedCmd}${output}`);
              ^

Error: Command failed: npm run serve
    at makeError (/home/chumbers/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /home/chumbers/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runNpmScript (/home/chumbers/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/util/runNpmScript.js:17:10) {
  code: 126,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null,
  failed: true,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'npm run serve',
  timedOut: false,
  killed: false
}

Node.js v20.10.0
```

Here is the line I am using to mount the drive in my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
#UUID=<my UID> /mnt/WIN_D ntfs defaults,nls=utf8,umask=0000,dmask=0002,fmask=0113,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names 0 0
```

I have tried a number of different configurations for mounting the drive. This includes the suggestions from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62453948/vue-cli-service-permission-denied-while-running-npm-run-serve?newreg=30904f07283f431f870acfd1fd060a93) to run `chmod -R a+x node_modules` and to add `exec` to the fstab line. The only way I have been able to get the command to work is if I mount the **both** files and directories in the drive with all permissions (i.e. 777).

This is not ideal. What confuses me is that if I create the default Vue application (with `vue create`) once on the NTFS drive and once on my home drive, `vue serve` only works on the home drive even when I mount the NTFS drive with precisely the same permissions as the home drive:

[A screenshot of permissions for directories and folders on both home and NTFS drive that works on home but not on the NTFS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdPU0.png)

I am at a bit of a loss as to how to mount the drive correctly such that these commands don't fail *and* I don't have to mount files and directories with all permissions for user, group and other.