# npm install global in Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile, nvm

Trying to install [resume-cli](https://jsonresume.org/getting-started/) through docker but getting some permission errors on installing resume-cli.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]

RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
RUN nvm install 15.13.0

RUN npm install -g resume-cli --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
RUN npm install -g jsonresume-theme-paper
```

and i run: `docker build -t containernpm .`

where I get Error on `RUN npm install -g resume-cli --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root`:

```
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /root/.nvm/versions/node/v15.13.0/lib/node_modules/resume-cli/node_modules/puppeteer
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js
npm ERR! sh: 1: node: Permission denied
```

btw next line `RUN npm install -g jsonresume-theme-paper` (with `-g`) runs normally without permission error.

Any idea how to overpass that without removing `-g` on `RUN npm install -g resume-cli --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root`
? (by removing `-g` runs without error)

Comment: Can it be that you need to say ```USER root``` before that commend and then set user back to what is was before? I guess you can get that user with ```RUN whoami```.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I know why the permissions errors are happening, but here is a Dockerfile that works.

```
FROM node:15.13.0-buster-slim
RUN npm install -g resume-cli
ENTRYPOINT ["resume"]
```

There is a related question ([sh: 1: node: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811564/sh-1-node-permission-denied)) but the top-voted answer there does not work for me.