# Deployment failed, bin/yarn: Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, npm, webpack, yarnpkg, tailwind-css

The deployment fails in production, it seems that yarn don't have rights to read the file.

How can i manage rights to yarn when deployment ? Thanks

Rails 6.1.3.1 // Node v15.5.1 // Tailwindcss: 2.1.1

production logs

```
   Using sassc-rails 2.1.2
 Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
 Running rake goals
 Run rake assets:precompile
 I,  INFO -- : Writing /home/bas/app/public/assets/BlackswanLostintheswell4-600x320-0d7f660ace7096482a4523c9ffe8a9f8908628a6b07f84919a5a7c9bc4fd5693.jpg
 I,  INFO -- : Writing /home/bas/app/public/assets/surf-de-nuit-bc6077c7ea2f8e710dd8263b861b5919ef8f1a17c6124f4bb57d70a9c2d7296f.jpg
 sh: line 1: /home/bas/app/bin/yarn: Permission denied
 sh: line 1: /home/bas/app/bin/yarn: Permission denied
 I,  INFO -- : Writing /home/bas/app/public/assets/application-1a626ce625d708fd518476b336900a049f858135a41f621a0d478a2fe04c738a.css
 I,  INFO -- : Writing /home/bas/app/public/assets/manifest-b4bf6e57a53c2bdb55b8998cc94cd00883793c1c37c5e5aea3ef6749b4f6d92b.js
 I,  INFO -- : Writing /home/bas/app/public/assets/manifest-b4bf6e57a53c2bdb55b8998cc94cd00883793c1c37c5e5aea3ef6749b4f6d92b.js.gz
 I,  INFO -- : Writing /home/bas/app/public/assets/8J0A9786-1-600x330-f70182bc6c594c2f565eb91f855afc917598392be56e5167b6f97cab5e9d0214.jpg
 I,  INFO -- : Writing /home/bas/app/public/assets/8J0A9786-9f645e58550403181de9430ffc80e1a838a606e5114f9f8828768911806f7bff.jpg
 I,  INFO -- : Writing /home/bas/app/public/assets/application-1a626ce625d708fd518476b336900a049f858135a41f621a0d478a2fe04c738a.css.gz
 I,  INFO -- : Writing /home/bas/app/public/assets/pages-1a626ce625d708fd518476b336900a049f858135a41f621a0d478a2fe04c738a.css
 I,  INFO -- : Writing /home/bas/app/public/assets/pages-1a626ce625d708fd518476b336900a049f858135a41f621a0d478a2fe04c738a.css.gz
 Compiling...
 Compilation failed:
 yarn run v1.22.10  
 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
 error Command "webpack" not found.
 Build failed. Please check the logs above
 Deploy failed
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "rails/webpacker#b6c2180",
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.2.0",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.2",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.4.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
    "node": "^16.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.2.10",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.1.1",
    "tailwindcss-debug-screens": "^2.0.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}
```

bin/yarn

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_ROOT = File.expand_path('..', __dir__)
Dir.chdir(APP_ROOT) do
  yarn = ENV["PATH"].split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR).
    select { |dir| File.expand_path(dir) != __dir__ }.
    product(["yarn", "yarn.cmd", "yarn.ps1"]).
    map { |dir, file| File.expand_path(file, dir) }.
    find { |file| File.executable?(file) }

  if yarn
    exec yarn, *ARGV
  else
    $stderr.puts "Yarn executable was not detected in the system."
    $stderr.puts "Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install"
    exit 1
  end
end
```

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1806
I gived rights to the local file but don't work

(local)/bin

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2945 Apr 15 12:09 bundle
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  141 Apr 15 12:09 rails
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   90 Apr 15 12:09 rake
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1068 Apr 15 12:09 setup
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  414 Apr 15 12:09 webpack
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  419 Apr 15 12:09 webpack-dev-server
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  533 Apr 15 12:09 yarn
```

[sh: 1: node: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811564/sh-1-node-permission-denied)
i tried:

```
yarn config set user 0
yarn config set unsafe-perm true
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem came from the installation of yarn in current work folder.

1. removed the yarn package from the folder with:

   sudo apt-get remove yarn && sudo apt-get purge yarn

and delete /node_modules, yarn.lock & /bin/yarn

2. change Yarn for Npm through webpacker with:

https://dmitryshvetsov.com/how-to-use-webpacker-with-npm-instead-of-yarn-rails-guide/

3. deploy
4. install yarn in a root folder.