# npm install -g yo generator-code is not working

Tags: node.js, npm, yo

Whenever I enter this command into my terminal

```
npm install -g yo generator-code
```

The module keeps on throwing me this error.

```
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/core-js
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
npm ERR! sh: 1: node: Permission denied

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-02-04T07_34_50_660Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sh: 1: node: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811564/sh-1-node-permission-denied)

Comment: I have already tried everything in this but it still isn't working.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like permission error.If you are using ubuntu OS, use **Sudo** command.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).