# How do I solve sh: 1: nx: Permission denied in Linux?

Tags: angular, linux, ubuntu, npm, virtual-machine

I'm trying to run an Angular application on Linux Virtual Machine using:

```
npm start
```

However, it says:

```
> application@1.28.2-rc-retail.2 start
> nx serve

sh: 1: nx: Permission denied
```

(that's it, nothing else)

According to this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811564/sh-1-node-permission-denied), I should try:

```
npm config set user 0
npm config set unsafe-perm true
```

However, it outputs:

```
npm ERR! code EUSAGE
```

Full output:

[image]

There's not much stackoverflow post regarding just "sh: 1: nx: Permission denied". Other people's errors are more descriptive than in my situation.

Why am I getting this error and how do I solve it? I would appreciate your knowledge and experience in this subject, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might get this under two conditions:

1. You didn't run the command from the directory where node_modules is installed (maybe one level up)
2. You don't have nx installed globally - you could try with `npx nx serve` instead