How to solve "Next Build: Permission Denied" On Server?
So I have a NextJS application running on a server with pm2. I was writing a Github Actions workflow to sync the repo on the server, build the application again and restart the pm2 process. However when the workflow comes to the next build stage, its giving me a permission denied error even though the server is being accessed as root.
This is the workflow file:
name: The Deployment Workflow 2

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: SSH Deploy
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PVT_KEY }}
          script: sh /home/deploy.sh

deploy.sh:
cd ~/nifty-tales
git pull
npm install
npm run build
pm2 restart nifty-tales

The error I am getting is:
out: > next builderr: sh: 1: next: Permission denied
I am not really sure how to fix this. I checked permissions and everything seems to be in order. Any help would be really appreciated.

Looks a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811564/sh-1-node-permission-denied. Please test and verify.

I tested chmod and even deleted the node modules but the problem still persists

Does deploy.sh work when you SSH directly on that machine?

yeah it works if I run it on the server

How do you run it on the server? Please add that in your question. Also, did you try this solution of removing existing module before installing the new ones?

Check once your deploy.sh inside /home directory and also try this: bash /home/deploy.sh
and give permission to the home directory: sudo chmod 755 /home
